# .OfType<>() Extract Derived types from a Base Type List

Tags: c#, lambda

Im not even sure if its possible to do what I am trying to do...
However, I have a List of Characters (`Character` is the base type), it contains a items that are derived from the `Character` type (like `Warriors` and `Mages`).

The inheritance chain is :

```
Character->Melee->Warrior 

Character->Spellcaster->Mage
```

I want to extract all mages and all warriors in a single line of code.

I managed to do it with `OfType`, but cant get it to work with `.Where`

**I've tried the following**

```
List<Character> chars = new List<Character>()
{
    new Warrior(),
    new Warrior(),
    new Warrior(),
    new Mage(),
    new Mage(),
    new Mage(),
};

List<Melee> melees = chars.OfType<Melee>().ToList(); // works
List<Melee> melee = chars.Where(c => c is Melee).ToList(); // doesnt work
```

**This is the error**

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 
>   System.Collections.Generic.List<MagicDestroyers.Characters.Character>
>   to 
>   System.Collections.Generic.List<MagicDestroyers.Characters.Melee.Melee>

Obviously I need to perform some typecasting, I just cant figure out where to do it?

Edit: The question is how to achieve the same result by using the `.Where` line with `c => c is Melee`, since its very easy to read.

Comment: Try using Linq `Enumerable.Cast<T>`. As you pointed out yourself, your version doesn't work because you are casting base class down to derived type (Character => Melee).

Comment: `I want to extract all mages and all warriors in a single line of code.` Sounds like you want a list that contains only mages and warriors, yet your code example does only one or the other, not both.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I just didnt include the rest of the code, yes I want to distribute the warriors and mages in 2 separate lists of <Melee> and <Spellcaster>.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius I dont know how to use the .Cast method, can you give me a hint:)

Comment: @Darkbound Try `var melees = chars.Where(x => x.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Melee)).Cast<Melee>();`

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius your .Cast suggestion is what I was looking for, the others showed me how to use it in the comments bellow, your other example may be working (I havent tried) but its hard to read

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is asking the framework to figure out a little bit too much:

```
List<Melee> melee = chars.Where(c => c is Melee).ToList(); // doesnt work
```

Even though you're using `Where` to filter out items that are only of type `Melee`, the list you're filtering is of type `Character`. So no matter how you filter the list of `Character`, the result is an `IEnumerable<Character>`, or `List<Character>` after calling `ToList()`.

You can't assign a `List<Character>` to a variable declared as `List<Melee>`.

You could do

```
List<Melee> melee = chars.Where(c => c is Melee).Cast<Melee>().ToList();
```

but the previous line where you use `OfType` is simpler and clearer. `OfType` is doing the same thing - selecting elements of the given type and casting them as that type.

Comment: Good explaination!

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for, yeah I agree that the .OfType is easier to read, I just couldnt figure out why I cant get it to work with the .Where and wanted to find out how to do it :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't really have a clear question, as your first example works fine, but if you *have* to use `.Where()` then you simply need to call `Cast<T>()` afterwards.

> I want to distribute the warriors and mages in 2 separate lists of  and

So either of these work, I would pick `OfType()` because it's more direct.

```
List<Melee> melees = chars.OfType<Melee>().ToList(); 
// or
List<Melee> melees = chars.Where(c => c is Melee).Cast<Melee>().ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, I edited my post, I managed to get the .OfType working while I was writing the question. So the question was how to make it work with .Where and you just solved it. Interestingly enough I thought I've tried your way, but obviously I did something wrong, it works perfectly!